# Block matrices. Each submatrix is a permuation of an original matrix at the diagonal.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations, diagonalization, block-matrices

Suppose that we have a matrix M which consists of block matrices with the same dimensions.

\begin{equation}
  M=\begin{pmatrix}
   A&D&0&0\cdots&0&0\\
   D&P^{-1}AP&D&0\cdots&0&0\\
   0&D&P^{-2}AP^2&D\cdots&0&0\\
   \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
   0&0&0&0\cdots&D&P^{-n}AP^n
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation}

Suppose that A is a matrix whose eigenproblem we have solved and D is a diagonal matrix with arbitrary constants. The P matrix is the prmutation matrix and its action on $A$ permutates its rows and columns. For example:

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{11}&c_{12}&c_{13}\\
c_{21}&c_{22}&c_{23}\\
c_{31}&c_{32}&c_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
P^-1AP=\begin{pmatrix}
c_{33}&c_{31}&c_{32}\\
c_{13}&c_{11}&c_{12}\\
c_{23}&c_{21}&c_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and

$$
P^{-2}AP^2=\begin{pmatrix}
c_{22}&c_{23}&c_{21} \\
c_{32}&c_{33}&c_{31} \\
c_{12}&c_{13}&c_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My question is this: "can we solve the eigenproblem of the $M$ matrix?"

Comment: The matrix that you have written is not square; I suspect that the final column should not be there

Comment: Even without the permutation matrix, there is no closed form (no "formula") for the eigenvalues of $M$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$

Comment: Ty very much a made the changes. But is there a special case? For example, if there are no permutations in the problme, then I think that a Discrete-Sin-Fourier-Trasform makes the problem much simpler.

Comment: If there are no permutations **and** the diagonal matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix, then the problem is indeed much simpler and a closed form solution exists. You might be onto something with the DSFT transform idea; I don't think that you would get a closed form, but you might reduce the problem to $n$ separate eigenproblems

Answer (score 1):

A consideration of the case without a permutation matrix: the matrix $M$ can be written as the sum of [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $M = I \otimes A + J \otimes D$, where $I$ denotes an identity matrix (of size $n+1$) and $J$ denotes the (size $n+1$) square matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0&\ddots\\
&\ddots&\ddots&1\\&&1&0}.
$$
Let $F$ denote a ["DST-I matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform) (I'm not sure if this is standard terminology), whose columns are the orthonormal set of vectors
$$
\vec v_j = C_j\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi j(1)}{n+2} \right), \dots, \sin\left(\frac{\pi j(n+1)}{n+2} \right)\right], \quad j = 1,\dots,n+1
$$
for a suitable normalization constant $C_j$. We find that $F^TJF$ is diagonal with $$
D_J = \text{diag}\left(-2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi(1)}{n+2}\right), \dots, -2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{n+2}\right)\right),
$$
so that $M$ is (orthogonally) similar to the matrix
$$
\begin{align*}
(F \otimes I)^TM(F \otimes I) &= 
(F \otimes I)^T[I \otimes A + J \otimes D](F \otimes I)
\\ & = (F^TIF) \otimes A + (F^TJF) \otimes D
\\ & = I \otimes A + D_J \otimes D, 
\end{align*}
$$
which is block diagonal of the form
$$
I \otimes A + D_J \otimes D = 
\text{diag}\left(A - 2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi(1)}{n+2}\right)D, \dots,A -2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi(n+1)}{n+2}\right)D\right).
$$
Thus, the problem of finding the eigenvalues of $A$ is reduced to that of finding the eigenvalues of $A + \lambda_j D$ for $j = 1,\dots,n+1$, where $\lambda_j = - 2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi j}{n+2}\right)$.

There is no closed form for these eigenvalues in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $D$.